# "Lazy" cases with expl3?

Tags: macros, conditionals, expl3, cases

**Problem**: i would like to have a command, which takes one mandatory and one optional argument. If the optional argument exist, select the corresponding case, otherwise return all case opportunities. Depending on the type of the #2 argument, it returns different fruits (#1). I do not know, how to solve efficiently/elegantly/(at all) the otherwise part, of the nested "cases". I do not like to hardtype the "[return all cases]" part, as it was way too much typing. Not for the present example, but in the case I would like to use this code for. The part I am not able to solve is, how to return all cases without hardtyping.

The optional argument can take values only, 00,10,01,11,20,02.

Preferably I would like to solve this problem within the expl3 framework.

**Pseudo code**:

```
if #2
{basket}{
        if #1 exist:
              case #1
                    {01}{kiwi}
                    {11}{mango}
                    {02}{papaya}
                    otherwise: [return all cases separated with "+"]
       }
{bowl}{ 
        if #1 exist:
              case #1
                    {00}{apple}
                    {10}{pear}
                    {20}{banana}
                    otherwise: [return all cases separated with "+"]
       }
```

Input:

```
\whatfruitinwhat[01]{basket}
\whatfruitinwhat{basket}
\whatfruitinwhat[20]{bowl}
\whatfruitinwhat{bowl}
```

**Output**:

```
There is kiwi in the basket.
There is kiwi + mango + papaya in the basket.
There is banana in the bowl.
There is apple + pear + banana in the bowl.
```

I appreciate your helps, Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the lists then use all or just one item:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_const:Nn\l_basket_clist{kiwi,mango,papya}
\clist_const:Nn\l_bowl_clist{apple,pair,banana}

\NewDocumentCommand\whatfruitinwhat{O{0}m}{
  \int_compare:nTF{0 = #1}
   {\clist_use:cn{l_#2_clist}{ + }}
   {\clist_item:cn{l_#2_clist}{#1}}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

1 \whatfruitinwhat[1]{basket}

2 \whatfruitinwhat{basket}

3 \whatfruitinwhat[3]{bowl}

4 \whatfruitinwhat{bowl}

\end{document}
```

---

In comments you indicated you want arbitrary keys rather than numeric index, so using an l3prop rather than clist:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_const_from_keyval:Nn\c_basket_prop{
zz=kiwi,
ZZ=mango,
99=papya}
\prop_const_from_keyval:Nn\c_bowl_prop{
zzz=apple,
Z=pair,
02=banana}

\NewDocumentCommand\whatfruitinwhat{om}{
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \tl_set:Nn\l_sep{}
    \prop_map_inline:cn{c_#2_prop}{\l_sep ##2 \tl_set:Nn\l_sep{+} }
   }
   {\prop_item:cn{c_#2_prop}{#1}}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

1 \whatfruitinwhat[zz]{basket}

2 \whatfruitinwhat{basket}

3 \whatfruitinwhat[02]{bowl}

4 \whatfruitinwhat{bowl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `\l_zzz_basket_clist` and `\l_zzz_bowl_clist`?

Comment: Constants should be prefixed by `c`, not `l`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ich hatte die deutsche Tastatur ausgewählt und konnte z . nicht finden

Comment: @egreg it was a variable originally, I switched to const later, but yes:-)

Comment: Unfortunately, i can not just simply the list members by numbers, because my optional argument takes values, such: 00, 01,10,11,20,02. Sorry for being confusing, I correct the question.

Comment: @keenOnTex l3prop version added

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I found the Z

Comment: Does the \lastbox command have an alterantive, which works in math mode, as well?

Comment: @keenOnTex Fixed version, now doesn't add + on first step rather than removing it  on the last step

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this is super,  thank you! Just one last question: how it was possible to make it work with keyvals containing numbers / in extreme case, being only 2 digits? - I know, and I am sorry, lesson learnt with not being precise at the problem statement. I had to consider "trying to abstract from concrete problem and make it easy to understand" vs "asking the exact problem, which is too specific".

Comment: zB \whatfruitinwhat[00]{11} returns kiwi, but \whatfruitinwhat{11} returns kiwi + mango + papaya?

Comment: @keenOnTex sorry I don't understand that comment, you have the mandatory argument being `11` in the comment but only `bowel` and `basket` are supported. the optional argument `[00]` would work if you use a `00` key in the initial setup of the property list.

Comment: I meant, if it was possible somehow that the mandatory argument is not a string of only-letters  (like recently bowl/basket), but 2 digits.  The motivation behind all, that i have a tensor quantity in 3D space (T^11,T^12,...T^33). Each of the component is expanded into Taylor-series. The mandatory argument were, the index of the tensor component (11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33), and the optional argument (00,10,01,11,20,02) is referring to one member of the taylor expansion of the given tensor component.

Comment: @keenOnTex apart from error checking thats alreadythere isn't it? nothing is stopping you replace `basket` with `11` in the above

Comment: This is true, and i have done so, before asking about it. Unfortunatelly, I got error when i replaced ```basket``` to ```11``` in the line ```\prop_const_from_keyval:Nn\c_basket_prop{... ```  and then called ```\whatfruitinwhat{11}```.
the error was :
"! LaTeX3 Error: Missing/extra '=' in '1' (in '..._keyval:Nn') Type <return> to continue. ... l.333 \prop_const_from_keyval:Nn\c_1 1_prop{ ? ! Emergency stop. ... l.333 \prop_const_from_keyval:Nn\c_1 1_prop{"

Comment: @keenOnTex oh you can't have numbers in csnames so use  `\prop_const_from_keyval:cn{c_11_prop}{` so the name is generated not using `\....`

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

This is fully expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\whatfruitinwhat}{om}
 {% #1 = optional index, #2 = name of container
  \prop_if_exist:cTF  { l_keenontex_fruit_#2_prop }
   {% the list exists
    \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
     {% no index
      \keenontex_fruit:n { #2 }
     }
     {% index
      \keenontex_fruit:nn { #2 } { #1 }
     }
   }
   {% the list doesn't exist
    \msg_error:nnn { fruit } { not-exist } { #2 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\definecontainer}{mm}
 {% #1 = name of container, #2 = items
  \prop_clear_new:c { l_keenontex_fruit_#1_prop }
  \clist_clear_new:c { l_keenontex_fruit_#1_clist }
  \prop_set_from_keyval:cn { l_keenontex_fruit_#1_prop } { #2 }
  \prop_map_inline:cn  { l_keenontex_fruit_#1_prop }
   {
    \clist_put_right:cn { l_keenontex_fruit_#1_clist } { ##2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \keenontex_fruit:n
 {
  \clist_use:cn { l_keenontex_fruit_#1_clist } { + }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \keenontex_fruit:nn
 {
  \prop_if_exist:cTF { l_keenontex_fruit_#1_prop }
   {
    \prop_if_in:cnTF { l_keenontex_fruit_#1_prop } { #2 }
     {
      \prop_item:cn { l_keenontex_fruit_#1_prop } { #2 }
     }
     {
      \msg_error:nnnn { fruit } { no-item } { #1 } { #2 }
     }
   }
   {
    \msg_error:nnnn { fruit } { not-exist } { #1 }
   }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { fruit } { not-exist }
 { Non~existent~container~#1 }
 { The~container~#1~has~not~been~defined }
\msg_new:nnnn { fruit } { no-item }
 { Non~existent~item~#2~in~container~#1 }
 { The~container~#1~contains~no~#2~item }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definecontainer{basket}{
  01=kiwi,
  11=mango,
  02=papaya
}
\definecontainer{bowl}{
  00=apple,
  10=pear,
  20=banana
}

\begin{document}

\whatfruitinwhat[01]{basket}

\whatfruitinwhat{basket}

\whatfruitinwhat[20]{bowl}

\whatfruitinwhat{bowl}

\whatfruitinwhat{foo}

\whatfruitinwhat[4]{basket}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The console will print

```
! Package fruit Error: Non existent container foo

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.75 \whatfruitinwhat{foo}

? h

The container foo has not been defined

?

! Package fruit Error: Non existent item 4 in container basket

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.77 \whatfruitinwhat[4]{basket}

? h

The container basket contains no 4 item

?
```

for the cases where the `foo` container is called or the container has no item with the specified key.

Comment: Seems there are no property-list-pendants (`\prop_use...`-functions) to the `\clist_use:...`-functions. I assume there being a good reason for this and I would like to learn about it. (I think about attempting to implement them as an exercise in getting used to expl3. So please don't do it for me. :-) )

Comment: @UlrichDiez There is no “order” in property lists, so I don't think a `\prop_use:...` function could do anything sensible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.I think there are scenarios where you can do something sensible.;-) With a `\prop_use...`-thing one probably could anticipate that order comes into being in the same way in which order comes into being when mapping a property-list with no order to a comma-list with order.But then you would have, besides things like `\prop_map_inline:cn{...}{\clist_put_right:cn {...}{...}}`, another place where the concept of a property-list without order is countered.Now that I've gotten food for thought from you, I don't like the idea of a `\prop_use...`-thing any more.Thanks. :-)

Comment: Thank you for Ulrich and egreg as well :)!